# Using display:block for one of the elements inside <a></a>?

Tags: html, html-lists

What kind of HTML element can i put inside `<a></a>` fairly? 
I love to make the following

```html
<a href="#" title="Click the icon">
    <div style="display: block; padding: 1em; background-image: url('1_tn.png'); text-indent: -9000;">
        <h3>
            Lorem ipsum
        </h3>
    </div>
</a>
```

or

```html
<ul>
    <a href="#" title="Click the icon">
        <li style="display: block; padding: 1em; background-image: url('1_tn.png'); text-indent: -9999;">
            <h3>
                Lorem ipsum
            </h3>
        </li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

, but as i think is not acceptable. w3 validator saying the same.

maybe this can be a solution:

```html
<a href="#" title="Click the icon">
    <span style="display: block; padding: 1em; background-image: url('1_tn.png'); text-indent: -9999;">
        Lorem ipsum
    </span>
</a>
```

but in this case - as i think - transforming the `<span>` element to block isn't valid and can cause differences over browsers.

You have some experience about this?

Comment: You are looking for `display: inline`

Comment: Do you need to do it this way round? Could you nest the anchor inside the block and make it 100% width and height? I think some idea of the context here might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use image-replacement to make your h3 text into an image link, correct? Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/QKtWq/2/

HTML:

```
<h3>
  <a href="#" title="Click me!">Lorem ipsum</a>
</h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 {
    background: black url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png') no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    height:100px; /* usually set to the height of the image */
}
h3 a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

You could also set a specific width on h3 if you didn't want it to be 100%.

edit: removed display:block from h3 css. Headers are already block elements.

Answer (score 4):

The 4.01 spec basically says that the anchor element (or all inline elements) can't have block level children so the approach you're trying to take is not valid. Of course you can do it (the span approach is better for compatibility and because it should validate) but it wouldn't be semantic, if that matters to you.